# HTML 5 input date does not validated on change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, validation

I validate my model by using data annotations:

...

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a due date of the task")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    [DisplayName("Due Date")]
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
```

...

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DueDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DueDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "handler(event);" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DueDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need hiding error message when a correct date is chosen but it is validated only when the form is being submitted.

[image: just submitted the form]

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why it happens like this?

**UPD: Controller method**

```
public PartialViewResult Edit(Guid? id)
    {
        TaskViewModel tvm = new TaskViewModel();

        // if it is not new task
        if (id != null)
        {
            // retrieve the task from the store
            Task task = _repository.GetTask(id.Value);

            // fill metadata if the task was found
            if (task != null)
            {
                tvm.TaskId = task.TaskId;
                tvm.Title = task.Title;
                tvm.Notes = task.Notes;
                tvm.Priority = task.Priority;
                tvm.IterationPath = task.IterationPath;
                tvm.DueDate = task.DueDate;
                tvm.AssigneePerson = task.AssigneePerson;
            }
        }

        return PartialView("EditTaskView", tvm);
    }
```

Comment: You need to show your controller GET method (if that error message is being displayed initially, then it mas you have added a `ModelState` error)

Comment: I didn't add ModelState errors

Comment: Show your controller GET method!!

Comment: Do you mean the method which returns the view with the form?

Comment: Yes, but the one you have shown is returning a partial view. And that code will not display that error message, and it will not display `mm/dd/yyyy` in the datepicker (unless `task.DueDate` is `null`)

Comment: And as side note, your method is name `Edit` which means your editing an existing `Task` so if `id` is null, you should be returning a `HttpNotFoundResult`, not a view

Comment: The message is defined in the required attribute at the model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153547/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-dmitry-shevchuk).